# jest hangs indefinitely with yarn pnp

Tags: jestjs, yarnpkg

Just getting started with yarn v3 but hit a bit of a problem with jest not running they just hang indefinitely with no output at all.

#### Recreation steps

```
yarn set version berry

yarn init

yarn add -D jest

yarn jest
```

```json
// package.json
{
  "name": "yarn-again",
  "packageManager": "yarn@3.2.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^28.1.0"
  }
}
```

Anyone seen this before?

Comment: It seems a bug, need to upgrade node v16.14+. See https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/12544

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bump node to 16.14.2 or upper or try to run `yarn jest --runInBand` and check errors

Comment: I have the same issue and `--runInBand` also works but now the tests are much longer.

Comment: upgrading node to v16 works! (--runInBand as well on node v14)